# Multiple protractor tests creation using loops based on returned promise value

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I would like to dynamically generate `it` blocks based on the values returned by a promise. Something along these lines:

```
describe('Main Page', function() {
    var rowNumber=event.script1(); //---Getting promise return value from other.js file

    describe('my loopy test', function() {
        rowNumber.then(function(result) {
            console.log(result.row) //printing row number: 2
            let myData = parseInt(result.row) //passed to integer

            console.log(myData) ; //printing row numbe r:2
            for (let i = 0; i < myData; i++) {
                it('gets ' + myData + 'loopy', function () {
                    console.log(myData);
                });
            };
        });
    });
});
```

This does not work now, jasmine does not generate `it` tests here. How should I approach the problem?

Comment: What are you actually asking?

Comment: @KatePaulk edited and added my understanding of the question based on what I understand is happening and what I saw people asking in similar situations. Hope this is what the OP meant.